# adding read more link for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm fetching data from custom post type Products using  product-template.php like this

```
   <div class="container" style="margin-top: 20px;">
      <h1>Our Products</h1>
        <?php
         $args=array('post_type' => 'products');
         $query= new WP_Query($args);                               
         while ($query-> have_posts() ) : $query->the_post()?>
         <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
             <h1><?php echo the_title();?></h1>
             <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'full', array( 'class' => 'innerimages') );?>
         </div>

     <?php                                
        endwhile;
     ?>
   </div>
```

now what i want to do is title should be clickable and once clicked on next page i should be able to get all the details about clicked product how do i do this?

Comment: `the_permalink()` within the loop should work. And after `endwhile` use `wp_reset_postdata()` to reset your custom `WP_Query()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using,

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 20px;">
      <h1>Our Products</h1>
        <?php
         $args=array('post_type' => 'products');
         $query= new WP_Query($args);                               
         while ($query-> have_posts() ) : $query->the_post()?>
         <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
             <!-- Add permalink as below -->
             <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h1><?php echo the_title();?></h1></a>
             <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'full', array( 'class' => 'innerimages') );?>
         </div>

     <?php                                
        endwhile;
     ?>
   </div>
```

And then for details you have to create `'single-products.php'` file and in that access your post details like,

```
<div>
    <?php the_post(); ?>
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <div><?php the_content(); ?></div>

    .......
</div>
```